# Shirk by thought

Tags: shirk, forgiveness, waswasa

I keep having thoughts and saying In Jesus we pray , Amen, In my head. I Say Astaghfirullah repeatedly and say the Shahada as well. I keep thinking about it because it stresses me out which bring the thoughts to my mind. Am I committing shirk?

Comment: https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6664

Answer (score 0):

Alsalam alikum brother/sister. Inshallah don't worry the prophet [pbuh] said

> "Allah forgives my followers those (evil deeds) their souls may whisper or suggest to them as long as they do not act (on it) or speak."
> [Source](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6664)

So the things that we have in our mind as long as we don't act upon it inshallah it is no problem I would just recommend that you pray for shelter from Shaitan by Allah [swt]